# WebApi - action paramer is null when using [FromBody] attribute and POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, owin, model-binding

I have this controller and I can't figure out, why `name` parameter is null

```
public class DeviceController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public void Select([FromBody]string name)
    {
        //problem: name is always null
    }
}
```

here is my route mapping:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ActionApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
    );

    appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
}
```

and here is my request:

```
POST http://localhost:9000/api/device/Select HTTP/1.2
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:9000
Content-Length: 16
Content-Type: application/json

{'name':'hello'}
```

I also tried to change body to plain string: `hello`.

```
POST http://localhost:9000/api/device/Select HTTP/1.2
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:9000
Content-Length: 5
Content-Type: application/json

hello
```

The request returns 204 which is ok, but the parameter is never mapped to a posted value.

*I'm using self hosted owin service.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first example You were using a complex object `{'name':'hello'}` when the `[FromBody]` attribute told the binder to look for a simple type.

In the second example your provided value in the body could not be interpreted as a simple type as it was missing quotation marks `"hello"`

**Using [FromBody]**

To force Web API to read a **simple type** from the request body, add the [FromBody] attribute to the parameter:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string name) { ... }
```

In this example, Web API will use a media-type formatter to read the value of name from the request body. Here is an example client request.

```
POST http://localhost:5076/api/values HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:5076
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 7

"Alice"
```

When a parameter has [FromBody], Web API uses the Content-Type header to select a formatter. In this example, the content type is "application/json" and the request body is a raw JSON string (not a JSON object).

At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body. So this will not work:

```
// Caution: Will not work!    
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string name) { ... }
```

The reason for this rule is that the request body might be stored in a non-buffered stream that can only be read once.

Source: [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: I do have FromBody parameter. The difference is that I'm using custom action

Comment: Look at the example request and compare it to your request. You will notice that you are posting an object `{'name':'hello'}` as opposed to a **simple type** like `"hello"`

Comment: As I wrote im my question I've tried to post plain string, but I was missing the quotations marks. I posted `hello`, instead `"hello"`. I will mark this as an correct asnwer, since it led to to solution, but please mention the quotation marks in your answer just for case somebody else forgets the quotes as I did