# C# WebApi POST Method and TypeScript

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, typescript, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to call a simple method using TypeScript code and also with Chrome Advanced Rest Client and I'm getting 404 error.

## WebApi Method

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/offert/TestPost")]
public IHttpActionResult TestPost(int idid)
{
    //http://localhost/prova/api/offert/TestPost

    var anonymousTypeVar = new { x = 15, y = 120 };
    return Json(anonymousTypeVar);
}
```

## TypeScript Code

```
var data = { idid: 1};

this.baseUrl = 'http://localhost/prova/api/offert/';
this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "TestPost", JSON.stringify(data), 
this.getRequestOptions)
      .map(response => response.json())
      .subscribe();
```

In this moment I'm still getting 404 error...

I know that I can concatenate the url passing "?idid=1" as parameter but I want to pass a Json string to the webmethod...

How I have to change the code?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is `http://localhost/` and not `http://localhost:XXXX/` where XXXX is some port number? Did you try viewing that URL in browser? Any result?

Comment: Also why there is `prova` there, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the url is correct...
If I change it from HttpPost to HttpGet and I call it with direct url: "http://localhost/prova/api/offert/TestPost?idid=1" I can get the response

Comment: Does it work if you don't stringify, but just pass the object in?

Comment: @DarioN1 check out my answer to something similar http://stackoverflow.com/a/36621476/5233410

Comment: @mgiesa no, it doesn't work

Comment: What if you add [FromBody] as a parameter attribute on the action like TestPost([FromBody] int idid)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if your JSON data is the problem... I'm sure MVC would happily map a URL or Body with key value pairs to a simply parameter, i.e.

```
idid=1 -> int id
```

But you will be passing:

```
{ idid: 1 }
```

Which needs to be mapped to...

```
public class OffertRequest
{
    public int idid { get; set; }
}
```

So your API would be:

```
public IHttpActionResult TestPost(OffertRequest idid)
```

Alernatively, pass a simply key/value pair in the request body.

Comment: Ok, thanks, your solution works for sure, but How I can I keep the webapi parameters as is and call it passing simply key/value ?

Comment: The format for a plain HTTP POST is as simple as `idid=1` in the body of the message - so where you use JSON.stringify, you should just pass this.